# JavaScript ToDo list, how to keep toggled classes after page refreshing

Tags: javascript

I was making ToDo List in JS: add new task, check task, remove task.
Aside from one thing everything is working fine.
The problem is that after adding new item to list it's displayed again and removes class "checked" from checked elements. I want to prevent it.
I was trying to remove function `clearList()`, which worked, but previous lists are kept on the screen.
How can I keep toggled classes after page refreshing?

```
"use strict";
let inputData = document.querySelector('[data-input-text]');
let inputTextData = document.querySelector('.to-do-new-input');
let btnAdd = document.querySelector('.btn-add');
let listContainer = document.querySelector('.to-do-list-wrapper');

let tasksList = [];

inputTextData.addEventListener('submit', e=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  addNewtask(inputData.value);
  inputData.value = null;
  displayList(...tasksList);
  checkTask();
  deleteTask(); 
})


function addNewtask(task){
  if(task==='') return;
  let newTask= task;
  tasksList.push(newTask);
}

function displayList(...list){
  clearList();
  list.forEach((item, index)=>{
    let taskRow = 
    `
    <div class="to-do-list-row" data-target-id="${index}">
        <div class="to-do-list-item">${item}</div>
        <div class="to-do-list-item-remove btn">
          <span class="material-icons btns-ico btn-check">check_circle</span>
          <span class="material-icons btns-ico btn-remove">delete</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    `;
    listContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', taskRow);
    

  })
 
}

function clearList(){
  while(listContainer.firstChild){
    listContainer.removeChild(listContainer.lastChild);
  }
}

function checkTask(){
  let btnsCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-check');
  btnsCheck.forEach(btn=>{
    btn.addEventListener('click',e=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      let taskTarget =  e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
      taskTarget.classList.toggle('checked');
    })
  })
}

function deleteTask(){
  let btnsDelete = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-remove');
  btnsDelete.forEach(btn=>{
    btn.addEventListener('click', e=>{
      let taskTarget =  e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
      let targetId = taskTarget.dataset.targetId;
      tasksList.splice(targetId, 1);
      taskTarget.remove(e.target.parentElement.parentElement);
    })
  })
}
```

Here is link to code and demo:
https://codepen.io/Nepri/pen/LYOXRLO

Thanks in advance.

I thought that it must be possible, so following answer in the comment I removed `clearList()` and changed `function addNewTask` and `function displayList` to keep past tasks and only add new one.
It worked, no clearing and toggled items are kept.
But it's still bugged, it's possible to only check every second task, or two in row if one was removed, some task are impossible to uncheck if new are not added.

If someone can check it and tell whats wrong I wll be really grateful.

```
"use strict";
let inputData = document.querySelector('[data-input-text]');
let inputTextData = document.querySelector('.to-do-new-input');
let btnAdd = document.querySelector('.btn-add');
let listContainer = document.querySelector('.to-do-list-wrapper');

let tasksList = [];
let id=tasksList.length;
let previousList;

inputTextData.addEventListener('submit', e=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  addNewTask(inputData.value);
  checkTask();
  deleteTask(); 
  let id=tasksList.length;
})

function addNewTask(input){
  if(input==='') return;
  let newTask = input;
  id++;
  tasksList.push({
    "id": id,
    "task": newTask,
    "status": false
  })
  inputData.value='';

    let lastAddedTask= tasksList.slice(-1);
    displayList(...lastAddedTask);
}

function displayList(...list){
  if(list===null)return;
  list.forEach(item=>{
    let listId = item.id;
    let listTask = item.task;
    let listStatus= item.status;

    let newRow=`
    <div class="to-do-list-row" data-target-id="${listId}">
    <div class="to-do-list-item">${listTask}</div>
      <div class="to-do-list-item-remove btn">
        <span class="material-icons btns-ico btn-check">check_circle</span>
        <span class="material-icons btns-ico btn-remove">delete</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    `;
    listContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', newRow);

  })
}

function checkTask(){
  let btnsCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-check');
  btnsCheck.forEach(btn=>{
    btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      btn.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle('checked');
    })
  })
}

function deleteTask(){
  let btnsDelete = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-remove');
  btnsDelete.forEach(btn=>{
    btn.addEventListener('click', e=>{
      let taskTarget =  e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
      let targetId = taskTarget.dataset.targetId;
      tasksList.splice(targetId, 1);
      taskTarget.remove(e.target.parentElement.parentElement);
    })
  })  
}
```

Comment: Can you properly state, what you are asking for, it is really ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am able to debug, there is some problem with `clearList()` function, just comment out the `clearList()` function in `displayList()` and see the behaviour.

In the `clearList()` function you are removing the previously added  elements and re-adding it further in the code flow. Because of this each `<div>` is losing the `checked` class on them.

Try storing the elements which are already checked in the memory and when you are displaying the list after addition of new task, just check which tasks where checked previously and toggle them again.

Better use data structure as taskList = `[{taskname: T1, checked: false}....]`

Comment: I did follow your advice and fixed what I wanted, checked items are keept after adding new, but there is new bug. I can only check every second item on the list, or two in row if some removed, but then I can't uncheck them.